# Samba with LDAP auth stopped working when upgrading Xenial to Fossa

Tags: 20.04, samba, authentication, ldap

We run an open source Java web application, which provides the users with a Windows file share to upload lots of big files. When a new
user account is added, the web app writes a user record to a local
slapd, with the Samba Schema and the user’s password. The users are introduced to the system via
NSS, and samba server is set to provide homes for these users. This worked
since a decade, but **after I updated the Ubuntu 16 LTS to 20 LTS, some users cannot connect
to their share, while others can.** (Samba version
4.3.9-Ubuntu → version 4.11.6-Ubuntu) It looks like **users who never connected
before can’t connect, while users who connected before updating still can,** but I am guessing here.

The problem is reproducible using `smbclient` (so this is
not about a Windows setting):

**One user can log in successfully:**

```
root@the-server:# smbclient \\\\localhost\\user.ok -U user.ok
WARNING: The "encrypt passwords" option is deprecated
Enter MYAPP\user.ok's password:
Try "help" to get a list of possible commands.
smb: \> exit
```

**The other user can not:**

```
root@the-server:# smbclient \\\\localhost\\failing.user -U failing.user
WARNING: The "encrypt passwords" option is deprecated
Enter MYAPP\failing.user's password:
session setup failed: NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
```

(Of course, I am using the correct password.)

What I tried and found so far:

- I added `ReadWritePaths` to `smbd.service` and `nmbd.service` because the daemons complained that they cannot open their log files to write. Here, I also added directories that I found with name `samba/`, and the user homes directory as well:
- I tried setting `client use spnego = no` or `client ntlmv2 auth = no` or
  both in `smb.conf`, each time restarted deamons. Won’t fix it.
- I also tries setting `client ntlmv2 auth = yes` because I [read](https://serverfault.com/a/936645/147741) that this
  kind of authentication is based on an NTLM password hash. Won’t fix it.
- I created a new user in the web app. The new user cannot log in.
- I deleted a working user and recreated it with the same username, but
  different (previously never used) user number. The user can still log in.
- I tried setting `client min protocol = NT1` and `server min protocol = NT1`, just trying it. Won’t fix it.
- I tried setting the container directory of the user homes
  (`/usr/local/myapp/users`) to group `sambashare` and permissions `1770`. Won’t
  fix it.

**What might cause this behaviour?**

#### Configuration files and log

`smbd.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Samba SMB Daemon
Documentation=man:smbd(8) man:samba(7) man:smb.conf(5)
Wants=network-online.target
After=network.target network-online.target nmbd.service winbind.service

[Service]
Type=notify
NotifyAccess=all
PIDFile=/run/samba/smbd.pid
LimitNOFILE=16384
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/samba
ExecStartPre=/usr/share/samba/update-apparmor-samba-profile
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/smbd --foreground --no-process-group $SMBDOPTIONS
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
LimitCORE=infinity
ReadWritePaths=/var/log/samba/
ReadWritePaths=/var/cache/samba/
ReadWritePaths=/var/spool/samba/
ReadWritePaths=/usr/local/myapp/users/

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

`smb.conf`:

```
[global]
log level = 4
log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
workgroup = MYAPP
unix extensions = no
wide links = yes
load printers = no
security = user
invalid users = root
encrypt passwords = yes
passdb backend = ldapsam:ldap://127.0.0.1
ldap suffix = dc=nodomain
ldap user suffix = ou=users
ldap group suffix = ou=groups
ldap admin dn = cn=admin,dc=nodomain
ldap ssl = no
ldap passwd sync = yes
ldap delete dn = no

[homes]
comment = Home Directories
path = /usr/local/myapp/users/%U
read only = no
browseable = no
valid users = %S
guest ok = no
inherit permissions = yes
```

`nssswitch.conf`:

```
passwd:         compat systemd ldap
group:          compat systemd
shadow:         compat
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

User records from `slapcat`:

```
dn: cn=ok.user,ou=users,dc=nodomain
sambaLMPassword: CAA85EBCA5013DA4E39701B5DB7D953C
sambaPrimaryGroupSID: S-1-5-21-2939508899-399288318-4273609636-100
displayName: User who can log in
sambaLogonScript: _ok.user.bat
objectClass: top
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: shadowAccount
objectClass: sambaSamAccount
userPassword:: e01ENX1oQ1MyYlRpZnl3eVlBdXhvSmdxc1N3PT0=
uid: ok.user
cn: ok.user
sambaPwdLastSet: 1590661108
loginShell: loginShell
sambaAcctFlags: [U          ]
gidNumber: 100
sambaPwdMustChange: 2147483647
sambaNTPassword: 76E562A44397461C150C451A0A97D45E
gecos: gecos
sambaSID: S-1-5-21-2939508899-399288318-4273609636-3017
description: description
homeDirectory: /usr/local/myapp/users/ok.user
sambaKickoffTime: 0
sn: ok.user
sambaPasswordHistory: 00000000000000000000000000000000000000
structuralObjectClass: inetOrgPerson
entryUUID: 51216ed8-3518-103a-9360-e9248c519c0b
creatorsName: cn=admin,dc=nodomain
createTimestamp: 20200528101828Z
uidNumber: 1007
sambaLogonHours: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
entryCSN: 20210204063107.618683Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: cn=admin,dc=nodomain
modifyTimestamp: 20210204063107Z

dn: cn=failing.user,ou=users,dc=nodomain
sambaPrimaryGroupSID: S-1-5-21-2939508899-399288318-4273609636-100
displayName: User who cannot log in
sambaLogonScript: _failing.user.bat
objectClass: top
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: shadowAccount
objectClass: sambaSamAccount
uidNumber: 1010
uid: failing.user
cn: failing.user
loginShell: loginShell
sambaAcctFlags: [U          ]
gidNumber: 100
sambaPwdMustChange: 2147483647
gecos: gecos
sambaSID: S-1-5-21-2939508899-399288318-4273609636-3021
description: description
homeDirectory: /usr/local/myapp/users/failing.user
sambaKickoffTime: 0
sn: failing.user
sambaPasswordHistory: 00000000000000000000000000000000000000
structuralObjectClass: inetOrgPerson
entryUUID: c65fc8da-4e3f-103a-9362-e9248c519c0b
creatorsName: cn=admin,dc=nodomain
createTimestamp: 20200629103354Z
userPassword:: e01ENX1PM0FNYzBuWW9UYlFqY1FUbVVGLy93PT0=
sambaLMPassword: 5EB9213C5086DC258401FE06348FE504
sambaNTPassword: B918CFBDEC4953CF990B0BE1F7682F3B
sambaPwdLastSet: 1601620989
sambaLogonHours: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
entryCSN: 20210204065218.718848Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: cn=admin,dc=nodomain
modifyTimestamp: 20210204065218Z
```

Users showing in `getent passwd`:

```
ok.user:x:1007:100:gecos:/usr/local/myapp/users/ok.user:loginShell
failing.user:x:1010:100:gecos:/usr/local/myapp/users/failing.user:loginShell
```

`log.127.0.0.1` of successful login:

```
[2021/02/11 07:35:45.410237,  4] ../../libcli/auth/ntlm_check.c:363(ntlm_password_check)
  ntlm_password_check: Checking NTLMv2 password with domain [MYAPP]
[2021/02/11 07:35:45.410294,  4] ../../source3/auth/check_samsec.c:183(sam_account_ok)
  sam_account_ok: Checking SMB password for user ok.user
  
[…]

[2021/02/11 07:35:45.413121,  3] ../../auth/auth_log.c:635(log_authentication_event_human_readable)
  Auth: [SMB2,(null)] user [MYAPP]\[ok.user] at [Do, 11 Feb 2021 07:35:45.413088 UTC] with [NTLMv2] status [NT_STATUS_OK] workstation [THE-SERVER] remote host [ipv4:127.0.0.1:55130] became [THE-SERVER]\[ok.user] [S-1-5-21-2939508899-399288318-4273609636-3027]. local host [ipv4:127.0.0.1:445] 
  {"timestamp": "2021-02-11T07:35:45.413267+0000", "type": "Authentication", "Authentication": {"version": {"major": 1, "minor": 2}, "eventId": 4624, "logonId": "0", "logonType": 3, "status": "NT_STATUS_OK", "localAddress": "ipv4:127.0.0.1:445", "remoteAddress": "ipv4:127.0.0.1:55130", "serviceDescription": "SMB2", "authDescription": null, "clientDomain": "MYAPP", "clientAccount": "ok.user", "workstation": "THE-SERVER", "becameAccount": "ok.user", "becameDomain": "THE-SERVER", "becameSid": "S-1-5-21-2939508899-399288318-4273609636-3027", "mappedAccount": "ok.user", "mappedDomain": "MYAPP", "netlogonComputer": null, "netlogonTrustAccount": null, "netlogonNegotiateFlags": "0x00000000", "netlogonSecureChannelType": 0, "netlogonTrustAccountSid": null, "passwordType": "NTLMv2", "duration": 10517}}
[2021/02/11 07:35:45.413355,  2] ../../source3/auth/auth.c:322(auth_check_ntlm_password)
  check_ntlm_password:  authentication for user [ok.user] -> [ok.user] -> [ok.user] succeeded

[…]

[2021/02/11 07:35:45.425097,  4] ../../auth/auth_log.c:740(log_successful_authz_event_human_readable)
  Successful AuthZ: [SMB2,NTLMSSP] user [THE-SERVER]\[ok.user] [S-1-5-21-2939508899-399288318-4273609636-3027] at [Do, 11 Feb 2021 07:35:45.425081 UTC] Remote host [ipv4:127.0.0.1:55130] local host [ipv4:127.0.0.1:445]
  {"timestamp": "2021-02-11T07:35:45.425151+0000", "type": "Authorization", "Authorization": {"version": {"major": 1, "minor": 1}, "localAddress": "ipv4:127.0.0.1:445", "remoteAddress": "ipv4:127.0.0.1:55130", "serviceDescription": "SMB2", "authType": "NTLMSSP", "domain": "THE-SERVER", "account": "ok.user", "sid": "S-1-5-21-2939508899-399288318-4273609636-3027", "sessionId": "1e59857a-7fca-47ba-8e02-c7bb512caf81", "logonServer": "THE-SERVER", "transportProtection": "SMB", "accountFlags": "0x00000010"}}
[2021/02/11 07:35:45.425290,  3] ../../source3/smbd/password.c:139(register_homes_share)
  Adding homes service for user 'ok.user' using home directory: '/usr/local/myapp/users/ok.user'
[2021/02/11 07:35:45.425356,  3] ../../source3/param/loadparm.c:1572(lp_add_home)
  adding home's share [ok.user] for user 'ok.user' at '/usr/local/myapp/users/%U'
```

`log.127.0.0.1` of failing login:

```
[2021/02/11 07:37:46.762028,  4] ../../libcli/auth/ntlm_check.c:363(ntlm_password_check)
  ntlm_password_check: Checking NTLMv2 password with domain [MYAPP]
[2021/02/11 07:37:46.762080,  4] ../../libcli/auth/ntlm_check.c:377(ntlm_password_check)
  ntlm_password_check: Checking NTLMv2 password with uppercased version of domain [MYAPP]
[2021/02/11 07:37:46.762118,  4] ../../libcli/auth/ntlm_check.c:391(ntlm_password_check)
  ntlm_password_check: Checking NTLMv2 password without a domain
[2021/02/11 07:37:46.762154,  3] ../../libcli/auth/ntlm_check.c:403(ntlm_password_check)
  ntlm_password_check: NTLMv2 password check failed
[2021/02/11 07:37:46.762178,  3] ../../libcli/auth/ntlm_check.c:448(ntlm_password_check)
  ntlm_password_check: Lanman passwords NOT PERMITTED for user failing.user
[2021/02/11 07:37:46.762213,  4] ../../libcli/auth/ntlm_check.c:485(ntlm_password_check)
  ntlm_password_check: Checking LMv2 password with domain MYAPP
[2021/02/11 07:37:46.762249,  4] ../../libcli/auth/ntlm_check.c:514(ntlm_password_check)
  ntlm_password_check: Checking LMv2 password with upper-cased version of domain MYAPP
[2021/02/11 07:37:46.762283,  4] ../../libcli/auth/ntlm_check.c:543(ntlm_password_check)
  ntlm_password_check: Checking LMv2 password without a domain
[2021/02/11 07:37:46.762317,  4] ../../libcli/auth/ntlm_check.c:574(ntlm_password_check)
  ntlm_password_check: Checking NT MD4 password in LM field
[2021/02/11 07:37:46.762425,  3] ../../libcli/auth/ntlm_check.c:595(ntlm_password_check)
  ntlm_password_check: LM password and LMv2 failed for user failing.user, and NT MD4 password in LM field not permitted
[2021/02/11 07:37:46.762483,  4] ../../source3/smbd/sec_ctx.c:215(push_sec_ctx)
  push_sec_ctx(0, 0) : sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 2
[2021/02/11 07:37:46.762510,  4] ../../source3/smbd/uid.c:575(push_conn_ctx)
  push_conn_ctx(0) : conn_ctx_stack_ndx = 1
[2021/02/11 07:37:46.762534,  4] ../../source3/smbd/sec_ctx.c:319(set_sec_ctx_internal)
  setting sec ctx (0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 2
[2021/02/11 07:37:46.762595,  4] ../../source3/smbd/sec_ctx.c:437(pop_sec_ctx)
  pop_sec_ctx (0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 1
[2021/02/11 07:37:46.762627,  4] ../../source3/smbd/sec_ctx.c:215(push_sec_ctx)
  push_sec_ctx(0, 0) : sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 2
[2021/02/11 07:37:46.762652,  4] ../../source3/smbd/uid.c:575(push_conn_ctx)
  push_conn_ctx(0) : conn_ctx_stack_ndx = 1
[2021/02/11 07:37:46.762675,  4] ../../source3/smbd/sec_ctx.c:319(set_sec_ctx_internal)
  setting sec ctx (0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 2
[2021/02/11 07:37:46.762713,  4] ../../source3/smbd/sec_ctx.c:215(push_sec_ctx)
  push_sec_ctx(0, 0) : sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 3
[2021/02/11 07:37:46.762738,  4] ../../source3/smbd/uid.c:575(push_conn_ctx)
  push_conn_ctx(0) : conn_ctx_stack_ndx = 2
[2021/02/11 07:37:46.762762,  4] ../../source3/smbd/sec_ctx.c:319(set_sec_ctx_internal)
  setting sec ctx (0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 3
[2021/02/11 07:37:46.763220,  4] ../../source3/smbd/sec_ctx.c:437(pop_sec_ctx)
  pop_sec_ctx (0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 2
[2021/02/11 07:37:46.763268,  4] ../../source3/smbd/sec_ctx.c:437(pop_sec_ctx)
  pop_sec_ctx (0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 1
[2021/02/11 07:37:46.763297,  4] ../../source3/smbd/sec_ctx.c:215(push_sec_ctx)
  push_sec_ctx(0, 0) : sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 2
[2021/02/11 07:37:46.763323,  4] ../../source3/smbd/uid.c:575(push_conn_ctx)
  push_conn_ctx(0) : conn_ctx_stack_ndx = 1
[2021/02/11 07:37:46.763347,  4] ../../source3/smbd/sec_ctx.c:319(set_sec_ctx_internal)
  setting sec ctx (0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 2
[2021/02/11 07:37:46.763392,  4] ../../source3/passdb/pdb_ldap.c:1975(ldapsam_update_sam_account)
  ldapsam_update_sam_account: user failing.user to be modified has dn: cn=failing.user,ou=users,dc=nodomain
[2021/02/11 07:37:46.763419,  2] ../../source3/passdb/pdb_ldap.c:1168(init_ldap_from_sam)
  init_ldap_from_sam: Setting entry for user: failing.user
[2021/02/11 07:37:46.763448,  4] ../../source3/passdb/pdb_ldap.c:1988(ldapsam_update_sam_account)
  ldapsam_update_sam_account: mods is empty: nothing to update for user: failing.user
[2021/02/11 07:37:46.763484,  4] ../../source3/smbd/sec_ctx.c:437(pop_sec_ctx)
  pop_sec_ctx (0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 1
[2021/02/11 07:37:46.763515,  2] ../../source3/auth/auth.c:343(auth_check_ntlm_password)
  check_ntlm_password:  Authentication for user [failing.user] -> [failing.user] FAILED with error NT_STATUS_WRONG_PASSWORD, authoritative=1
[2021/02/11 07:37:46.763596,  2] ../../auth/auth_log.c:635(log_authentication_event_human_readable)
  Auth: [SMB2,(null)] user [MYAPP]\[failing.user] at [Do, 11 Feb 2021 07:37:46.763566 UTC] with [NTLMv2] status [NT_STATUS_WRONG_PASSWORD] workstation [THE-SERVER] remote host [ipv4:127.0.0.1:55160] mapped to [MYAPP]\[failing.user]. local host [ipv4:127.0.0.1:445] 
  {"timestamp": "2021-02-11T07:37:46.763720+0000", "type": "Authentication", "Authentication": {"version": {"major": 1, "minor": 2}, "eventId": 4625, "logonId": "0", "logonType": 3, "status": "NT_STATUS_WRONG_PASSWORD", "localAddress": "ipv4:127.0.0.1:445", "remoteAddress": "ipv4:127.0.0.1:55160", "serviceDescription": "SMB2", "authDescription": null, "clientDomain": "MYAPP", "clientAccount": "failing.user", "workstation": "THE-SERVER", "becameAccount": null, "becameDomain": null, "becameSid": null, "mappedAccount": "failing.user", "mappedDomain": "MYAPP", "netlogonComputer": null, "netlogonTrustAccount": null, "netlogonNegotiateFlags": "0x00000000", "netlogonSecureChannelType": 0, "netlogonTrustAccountSid": null, "passwordType": "NTLMv2", "duration": 9134}}
[2021/02/11 07:37:46.763836,  4] ../../source3/smbd/sec_ctx.c:437(pop_sec_ctx)
  pop_sec_ctx (0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 0
[2021/02/11 07:37:46.763882,  3] ../../auth/gensec/spnego.c:1442(gensec_spnego_server_negTokenTarg_step)
  gensec_spnego_server_negTokenTarg_step: SPNEGO(ntlmssp) login failed: NT_STATUS_WRONG_PASSWORD
[2021/02/11 07:37:46.763916,  4] ../../source3/smbd/sec_ctx.c:215(push_sec_ctx)
  push_sec_ctx(0, 0) : sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 1
[2021/02/11 07:37:46.763943,  4] ../../source3/smbd/uid.c:575(push_conn_ctx)
  push_conn_ctx(0) : conn_ctx_stack_ndx = 0
[2021/02/11 07:37:46.763966,  4] ../../source3/smbd/sec_ctx.c:319(set_sec_ctx_internal)
  setting sec ctx (0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 1
[2021/02/11 07:37:46.764015,  4] ../../source3/smbd/sec_ctx.c:437(pop_sec_ctx)
  pop_sec_ctx (0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 0
[2021/02/11 07:37:46.764055,  3] ../../source3/smbd/smb2_server.c:3254(smbd_smb2_request_error_ex)
  smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: smbd_smb2_request_erro
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is undoubtedly down to a couple of parameter defaults changing between Samba 4.3.9 and 4.11.6

At 4.3.9 these were the defaults:
server min protocol = LANMAN1
client min protocol = CORE

At 4.11.6 these changed to:
server min protocol = SMB2_02
client min protocol = SMB2_02

I am sure if you change them back, your problem will go away, but you should be aware that Samba is actively working on removing SMBv1, this will mean that you will no longer be able to use openldap with Samba. This will not happen at once, it may be a year or so, but it will happen, so I suggest you start planning to upgrade to Samba AD or similar

Comment: It looks like this fixes it for the most accounts. There is still one courious one left (which still refuses all and everything, even after deleting and recreating!) But thanks for your help!